# How to mask page/Modaldoalog window in hyperlinkfield?

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup, modal-dialog

I am using following code in gridview:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField runat="server" Text="Order" ItemStyle-Font-Underline="true" DataNavigateUrlFields="itemid" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="../Order.aspx?OID={0}" Target="_blank" />
```

A new popup window opens. But it remains open even if I close the main page(grid). How can I mask this popup ? I need to send ID of row clicked as querystring, hence using this code.

Can anyone help me with best way possible to achieve it and how to do that ? Masking or ModalDialog window or anything else ?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question 'How can I mask this popup?'

Comment: Mask would refer to a div. Modal refers to a popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a TemplateField and put a LinkButton in its ItemTemplate which will call the JS window.showModalDialog method.

```
<TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton id="btn" runat="server" OnClientClick="window.showModalDialog ('http://blah.com/d.aspx?p1=' + '<%# Eval("someField") %>'" ... />
    </ItemTemplate>
</TemplateField>
```

Comment: I didn't try to run this. If it gives you trouble with server tags not being well-formed, you will need to put the JS in a separate function inside a javascript tag higher up on the page

Comment: Thanks for pointer: the following works:      <asp:LinkButton ID="btn" runat="server" OnClientClick='<%# "openOrder(" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "itemid" ) + ")"%>'></asp:LinkButton>

Comment: And the OpenOrder contains a javascript window.showModalDialog

Comment: It's OK to upvote my answer when you accept it, folks.... I already got [Tenacious](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/225/tenacious)